# XCode 6 UILabel not refreshing text when calling from complition handler

Tags: xcode, view, swift, uilabel, refresh

I'm calling to refresh label after `refreshQuote()` function finishes. When look at the log to see what happened with `label.text` I can see it has been replaced however the view still looks the same.

Im calling `refreshQuote()` from `viewDidload`.
When calling `setQuoteLabel` directly from viewDidLoad it all works fine

Please help, loosing hope now.
Thanks in advance

```
func refreshQuote()
{

    var url : String = "https://api.parse.com/1/classes/Quotes"
    var request : NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest()

    request.addValue("------", forHTTPHeaderField: "X-Parse-Application-Id")
    request.addValue("------strong text", forHTTPHeaderField: "X-Parse-REST-API-Key")


    request.URL = NSURL(string: url)

    request.HTTPMethod = "GET"

    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue(), completionHandler:{ (response:NSURLResponse!, data: NSData!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        var error: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSError?> = nil

          NSLog(error.debugDescription);

        let jsonResult: NSDictionary! = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: error) as? NSDictionary

        if (jsonResult != nil)
        {
            var allResults: NSArray = jsonResult["results"] as NSArray
            var pickedResult: NSDictionary = allResults[0] as NSDictionary

            let q:String = pickedResult["message"] as String!

            self.setQuoteLabel(q);

        } else
        {

            // couldn't load JSON, look at error
        }
    })


}



func setQuoteLabel (quote:String)
{
    NSLog(quote)
    quoteLabel.text = quote;
    quoteLabel.setNeedsDisplay();
    NSLog(quoteLabel.text!)

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All UI components must be updated from the main thread, whereas in your case you are updating most likely from a different thread, because the code is in an asynchronous block.

To force a block of code to be executed in the main thread, you can use `dispatch_async` as follows:

```
dispatch_async (dispatch_get_main_queue ()) {
    self.setQuoteLabel(q)
}
```

Comment: For Swift 3, it should be DispatchQueue.main.async() { self.setQuoteLabel(q); }